# rename files in a directory to insert spaces before and after a dash

Tags: bash, whitespace, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a directory which contains the following type of files:

```
01.firstname surname-track1 name1.mp3
02.firstname surname-track2 name2.mp3
03.firstname surname-track3 name3.mp3
```

I'm looking for a BASH command to batch rename all my files in the directory so that there is a space before and after the dash, such as:

```
01.firstname surname - track1 name1.mp3
02.firstname surname - track2 name2.mp3
03.firstname surname - track3 name3.mp3
```

Any help most appreciated!

Comment: Use the `rename` command, it allows you to provide a pattern-based replacement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed Barmar, you can use rename (or file-name).
In your case :

```
file-rename 's/-/ - /g' *.mp3
```

It's regular expression based so it's very powerfull (and therefor dangerous), before running it, you can run it "dry", it will show you what your command is about to change :

```
file-rename -n 's/-/ - /g' *.mp3
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't quite get what I'm after, it gives:

01 - firstname surname - track1 name1.mp3

etc etc...

Can you make it so it gives:

01. firstname surname - track1 name1.mp3

? 

Your command is getting rid of the period after the track number, and I'd like to keep that ideally. Thanks!

Comment: Which `rename` are you using ? the one from utils-linux doesn't support regular expressions.

Comment: It's a perl package : /usr/bin/file-rename using File::Rename version 0.20

Comment: I'm just using the standard one with Ubuntu 18.04LTS. Should I install a different one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash parameter substitution:

```
for i in *.mp3; do mv $i ${i/-/ - }; done
```

Alternatively, you can use rename (from util-linux package)

```
rename '-' ' - ' *.mp3
```

Or prename (some distributions have this as rename i think, based on the above answer)

```
prename 's/-/ - /' *.mp3
```